# How to print the type of a variable- error when variable is integer

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project using Objectdb and Im using NetBeans.
I want to have a myString method that can appear this message : 
Variable type is int. 
when im calling the object Driver from another main class
[

```
 import javax.persistence.*;
 import java.util.*;
 //import javax.jdo.*;
 import java.sql.*;

 public class Main { 

public static void Element(Object obj){
    System.out.println(obj);
}//end method Element

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Element(Driver);

}//end main
```

]
Of course I don't want to type exactly this thing so I can print it,
but instead I want a method that can return int if its an integer, String if it is String etc.
**When it come to a String variable it is ok.
But when I have an integer it shows me the message "int cannot be dereferenced" so the compiler won't pass this.**
Is this a way to work it around correctly?
This is importart so thanks in advance.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class Driver{    

@Id 
    private int Driverid;

    public void setDriverid(int Driverid) {
        this.Driverid= Driverid;
    }

    public int getDriverid() {
        return Driverid;
    }

public Driver(int getDriverid){
        this.Driverid=Driverid; 
}

public String toString() {
        return  "Variable type is " + Driverid.getClass.getSimpleName() + "." ;
}//end toString

}//end class Driver
```

Comment: I believe it's called `Driverid.getClass()` and not `Driverid.getClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with using the `Integer` class instead of `int`. int is a primitive type, Integer is not.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are trying to determine at runtime something which is known at compile time, but you can use reflections.

```
public String toString() {
    return "Variable type is " + getDeclaredFields()[0].getType().getSimpleName() + "." ;
}
```

toString() prints

```
Variable type is int.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the instance type:

```
if(object instanceof Integer){...}
else if(object instanceof String){...}
```

Comment: You can't use `instanceof` on a primitive.

Comment: I get "error: unexpected type
required: reference
found:    int" from the compiler.  Perhaps you are thinking of wrapper classes.

Comment: You can't write "object instanceof int"... use Integer instead.
If this doesn't work, i'll check it in one of my projects!

Comment: Well, `int a = 10; if (a instanceof Integer)` can never work.. `Integer.valueOf(a) instanceof Integer` will work..

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot call `getClass()` on any `Primitive Type`... You can declare your `DriverId` as `Integer`, and get it worked..